# How to write a function that computes probabilities and uses the values to compute the corresponting theoretical quantiles

Tags: r, function, quantile

Extend the function `get_probs`: write a new function `get_qs` that first computes the probabilities as before (or by callicng `get_probs`), and then uses these values to compute the corresponding theoretical quantiles for the standard normal distribution. Also add these quantiles to the data.

below, the first part describes a dataframe similar to the one that I am working with.
The first get_probs function is fine, while I am still struggling with the get_qs.

I have tried also, as already suggested in the forum with the ntile function, but I it seems I do not answer the task.

```
###Dataframe

Country <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
Year <- c("1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004")
Gini_index <- c("51", "34", "44", "21", "33", "28")

df_example <- data.frame(Country, Year, Gini_index)

###get_probs function

vector_example <- c(1,0,-1,1,1,0)

get_probs_example <- function(vector_example) {
probs <- rank(vector_example)/length(vector_example)
return(probs)
}
print(get_probs(vector))

df_example$probs <- get_probs(df_example$Gini_index)

###get_qs function

vector_q_example <- qnorm(c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9))

get_qs_example <- function(vector_q_example) {
quantile <- quantile(get_probs(vector_q_example))/length(vector_q_example)
return(quantile)
}
print(get_qs(vector_q_example))

df_example$qs <- get_qs(df_example$Gini_index)

**Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, qs, value = c(`0%` = 0.0277777777777778,  : 
replacement has 5 rows, data has 6**
```

Comment: If I understand your question, the `quantile` values are fivenum, which would always be of the same length.  You may need to use the `quantile` to `cut` the output from `get_probs/length` to return the index i.e. `probs <- get_probs(vector_q_example);
 qtl <- quantile(probs)/length(vector_q_example);
 qtl[as.integer(cut(probs, breaks = qtl))]
 }`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I need, is to get this new get_qs function and add the values generated as an extra column to my data. To complete I have to make a qqplot of the quantiles vs Gini_index. _Extend the function get_probs: write a new function get_qs that first computes the probabilities as before (or by callicng get_probs), and then uses these values to compute the corresponding theoretical quantiles for the standard normal distribution. Also add these quantiles to the data_ this is the task concerning the quantile part.

Comment: The code I showed is the code you can use to replace the ones in `get_qs`.  Only issue with `quantile` divided by length is that it may return some values being `NA` with cut as those are not found in the probs, so the index from `as.integer` also have `NA` and thus `qtl[as.integer(...)]` will also returns NA for those values that are NA index

Comment: Thank you. It partially worked. As you said, I have severals NA, do you have any hint on how to get rid of NAs. I mean, ideally I would like to have a column with as many values as the rows are  (without NAs).

Comment: You can wrap with `-Inf`, and `Inf` i.e. `qtl[as.integer(cut(probs, breaks = c(-Inf, qtl, Inf)))]}` which would cover all the values below and above the quantile range

Comment: It still gives me NAs, sadly:  **get_qs <- function(vector_q) {
+   probs <- get_probs(vector_q);  
+   qtl <- quantile(probs)/length(vector_q);  
+   qtl[as.integer(cut(probs, breaks = c(-Inf, qtl, Inf)))]
+ } 
> print(get_qs(vector_q))
 
               100% <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
                0.2   NA   NA   NA   NA**

Comment: I think the issue is that you are dividing by length to create the qtl and then using `cut` on 'probs'

Comment: I have tried with **get_qs <- function(vector_q) {
  probs <- get_probs(vector_q);  
  qtl <- quantile(probs);  
  qtl[as.integer(cut(probs, breaks = c(-Inf, qtl, Inf)))]
} 

print(get_qs(vector_q))

df2$quantiles <- get_qs(df2$probs)** NA is not anymore present, but when I make the QQplot of the quantiles vs Gini_index it is just a weird plot. Probably I did something wrong and I did not get at all the point